# Spacing with li element

Tags: html, css

I want to have spacing within `li` block. Basically `Count` should be on right end on the `li` block, I tried word-spacing but that's effecting `User Name` as well:

```
<li style="font-size:14px;text-align:left">
   <strong>User Name</strong>
   <span style="font-size:14px;text-align:right;">Count</span>
</li>
```

Comment: That inline styling hurts my feelings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `float: right` to count. `text-align` wont work here.

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:right` instead of `text-align:right`.

```
<li style="font-size:14px;">
   <strong>User Name</strong>
   <span style="font-size:14px;float:right;">Count</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

> ul li:after { 
>       content: " Count";
>   }